# Laravel 5.4 image won't upload

Tags: image, upload, laravel-5.4, image-uploading, image-upload

This is my first time working with Laravel 5.4 or any Laravel for that matter. I migrated a perfectly good working website to a new host. Now when I go to upload an image from admin or a user account the image won't upload. I get the whoops! error.

I have fixed all the broken links I can find, but I can't find where to go to fix the image won't upload issue.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You should probably check the upload folder permissions. Check against the good website

Comment: yes, I did that already and they're 755 on the on both hosts.

Comment: What about the owner and the group? Also, check if the user running Apache is the same in both servers

Comment: Yes, everything is the same. Perhaps the db isn't populating the full sql. I will check this.

Comment: I doubt it, since you say it was working well on the other server. If everything else is working, it shouldn't be a problem with the database, most likely with the file system. But hey, anyway, if you find the problem please share your solution

Comment: I've re-ftped several times and still can't get the image to upload. I checked the server and it is set the same as my old server. I guess I'll chalk it up to gremlins in the machine until I can figure it out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you checked the server logs? Perhaps it's some misconfiguration of the server (max file size, max post size, etc)